# Where did Nautilus's panes go?

Tags: 13.10, nautilus

I used to be able to open a second nautilus pane/panel with <kbd>F3</kbd>, but that doesn't seem to work in 13.10 and I don't see anything about panes in prefs or menus. Where'd it go?

Comment: removed by Gnome starting in nautilus 3.6

Comment: Boo. Is that where the remaining file size reporting in the bottom right went, too?

Comment: Now AskUbuntu seems to notice that this is related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286428/extra-pane-split-view-in-file-manager?rq=1

Comment: users who want most of what Gnome has removed seem to like nemo, see this - http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments, removed by Gnome.